# Why are no reviews being printed out? Am I using the correct HTML elements?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to print out the paragraph portion of reviews from yelp for a specific restaurant. I am not sure if I am implementing the BeautifulSoup functions correctly. 
I am providing the code below.

I have seen similar implementation of the soup.find_all work. I figured that it was an issue of what I put in the attrs. I figured that it would be best to find all the div elements that had the same class name and contained the reviews.

```
for i in range (0,500,20):
    url = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/m%C3%A9m%C3%A9-mediterranean-new-york-4?start={}'.format(i)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
    for s in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'span class': 'lemon--span__373c0__3997G'}):
      re = s.find('p', attrs={'lang': 'en'})
      print(re.text)
```

Now when I run this code it does not print out any error. All it says is: "Process finished with exit code 0"
This leads me to believe that I am not using the right elements correctly or have messed up logic in the for loop.

Comment: `span class` is not a valid attribute. You can't use that to mean that it should look for a child span with that class.

Comment: Search for the span with the class you want, then get its parent and find the `p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html looks like a lot of it is dynamic e.g. the class names etc will change over time. I would grab from the `script` tag the review info and parse with a json library

```
import requests,json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.yelp.com/biz/m%C3%A9m%C3%A9-mediterranean-new-york-4')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('[type="application/ld+json"]').text.strip())
print(data)
```

---

If you want to do away with bs4 you could just regex out the required string.

```
import requests,json, re

r = requests.get('https://www.yelp.com/biz/m%C3%A9m%C3%A9-mediterranean-new-york-4')
p = re.compile(r'({"aggregateRating.+?(?=<))', re.DOTALL)
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0].strip())
```

[image]

Comment: When running each segment I get errors. When I do .text.strip() I get the AttributeError message saying 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. I think this means that whatever bs captures is empty.

Comment: With the next segment of code, I get an IndexError: List index is out of range. I think that for some reason the json with reviews/ratings is empty.